# "php -v" no such file or directory

Tags: php, homebrew

I'm try to upgrade php version using homebrew.
Although the latest version is installed, when I run the "php -v" command I get no results.

[image]

Comment: ```brew link php```

Comment: i've get the same error "no such file or directory"

Comment: Can you `brew unlink php@7.2`?